# How can I set up a chain of these RGB Smart Neopixel LEDs?

Tags: led

I have [these LEDs with me.](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1312?&main_page=product_info&products_id=1312) At the end of the day, I need to connect around 100 of these together, with each one being individually programmable.

I was testing connected the four of them I have together, going from 5V to 5V, Ground to Ground, and DataOut to DataIn, but once I connected two or more it started doing random things. They are supposed to just change from yellow to blue over and over, but sometimes they would turn green and red and other random colors for a second. Sometimes the first one in the chain would be stuck on yellow and the others would work properly. I am not sure what is causing this, any assistance is appreciated.

Also if you have a better suggestion for connecting 100 LEDs together with each one individually programmable, that would be great as well.

**EDIT**
Code I am using:

```
import time

from neopixel import *


# LED strip configuration:
LED_COUNT      = 1     
LED_PIN        = 18      .
LED_FREQ_HZ    = 800000  
LED_DMA        = 5      
LED_BRIGHTNESS = 255    
LED_INVERT     = False   

# Define functions which animate LEDs in various ways.
def colorWipe(strip, color, wait_ms=50):
    """Wipe color across display a pixel at a time."""
    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, color)
        strip.show()
        time.sleep(wait_ms/1000.0)

 Main program logic follows:
if __name__ == '__main__':

    strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA, LED_INVERT, LED_BRIGHTNESS)
    .
    strip.begin()

    print 'Press Ctrl-C to quit.'
    while True:
        # Color wipe animations.
        colorWipe(strip, Color(255,203,5))  # Maize wipe
        colorWipe(strip, Color(0,39,76))  # Blue wipe
```

My wiring set up is basically this https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/19659

Comment: What code are you using, how are you powering the LEDs?

Comment: @SteveRobillard I edited with the code I am using. I am powering the LEDs with a 5V power supply from Adafruit's website.